# Sonata Media Bundle missing entity Category

Tags: symfony, sonata, symfony-cmf, sonata-media-bundle

I try to install the Sonata Media Bundle into the Symfony CMF following this guide: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html. This command

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

makes a whole new bundle `ApplicationSonataMediaBundle` with a few entities:

- Gallery
- GalleryHasMedia
- Media

But i get the error that the entity Category does not exist when i want to go to the next step:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

This is the complete error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                                  
  The target-entity Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category cannot be found in 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Med  
  ia#category'.
```

Is there somebody who can help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
# sonata_classification.yml:

sonata_classification:
    # ...

doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                #metadata_cache_driver: apc
                #query_cache_driver: apc
                #result_cache_driver: apc
                mappings:
                    #ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle: ~
                    SonataClassificationBundle: ~
```

Comment: Is the classification bundle installed and registered?

Comment: new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(), .. yes it is

Comment: looks like you are not the only one : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/1084 . It might be a bug.

Comment: i see.. thanks for your update.

Answer (score 6):

I had to set this configuration options to get it to work:

```
sonata_media:
    class:
        media: Application\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        gallery: Application\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
        gallery_has_media: Application\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    # ...
```

And also:

```
doctrine_phpcr:
    # ...

    odm:
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            SonataMediaBundle:
                prefix: Sonata\MediaBundle\PHPCR
            ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:
                prefix: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\PHPCR
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after installing news bundle (which brings classification and media bundles with it). I configured both media and classification before news and received the same error as OP. After looking into the code I noticed that media bundle allows for another class to be specified for category. This stopped the error for me.

```
sonata_media:
    class:
        # my own bundle namespaces for media and classification bundles
        media: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        gallery: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
        gallery_has_media: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
        category: Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to create a [sonata_classification.yml](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/1084#issuecomment-234968114) file as described in [the classification docs](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataClassificationBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/doc/reference/installation.rst)

Comment: Thanks greg0ire, i copied and pasted the given example into that file. You can read it in my first post.  Should it be enough?

Comment: I'm not sure. Just try it, we'll see.

Comment: if i include sonata_classification.yml in config.yml then i am able to request the cmf pages. if i dont include it then the same error shows up as on the cli when i want to update the database but then for the entity media instead of the entity Category.

Comment: Either you include it, either you make sure it is loaded.

Comment: hey, you said "if I don't include it then the same error shows up", and now, it also show up when you do include it ?!?

Comment: no but it does when i want to update the database with app/console doctrine:schema:update

Comment: Oh ok. Were both entities generated though? If yes, were their mapping generated too? Can you check that?

Comment: As you can see i posted an answer. Now it looks like its working but i think i have still to configure sonata-admin to let the mediabundle appear somewhere... Thank you for your help greg0ire!

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem so:

```
// app/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        new Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```

and

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```